# arastta adding user session variable in opencart

Tags: php, session, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to figure out how to add a new user variable.
I have added the variable in db table users
I want to be able to access these new variables in the admin section by

```
$this->session->data['new_variable'];
```

How do I create this session variable upon successful login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
add a new user session variable in system/library/user.php

public function

db select statement get records
add session

```
$this->session->data['new_variable'] = $user_query->row['new_variable'];
```

then call for it where needed